# Regarding for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

why only 9 is printed after executing the codes below? Why the code is not printing 012345789 as the outcome:

```
digits = '0123456789'
result = 0

for digit in digits:
    result = digit

print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys! I wasn't trying to write a forloop to print 0123456789. This is actually a multiple choice question asking what will be printed after the code is executed. The answer for the question is 9. I am just wondering why.

Comment: What else could it be? `result` will be whatever was last assigned to it. Since we're iterating on a non-empty sequence and assigning to `result` it's going to be whatever `digit` is in the last iteration, which is `'9'`. In Python strings are iterable and iterating them yields their "characters" in order. If strings were not iterable, this would generate an error. There is no situation in which `'012345789'` is a possible output.

Answer (score 1):

The print statement is in the wrong scope. You code would only print the final value of result. Change to this:

```
digits = '0123456789' 
result = 0
for digit in digits: 
    result = digit
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

"This is actually a multiple choice question asking what will be printed after the code is executed. The answer for the question is 9. I am just wondering why."

The loop iterates over each character in the string `digits`, and for each character in that string assigns the value to `result`. It isn't cumulative, so at the end of the loop the only value in `result` is the last one, or 9.

That's why 9 gets printed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = [] 
for digit in digits: 
result.append(digit)

print(''.join(result))
```

If you are trying to print it all in one line like '0123456789', this will be able to print it on the same line.

Or, you could indent properly and put `end=''` at the end of the print statement to put them all together, like follows:

```
for digit in digits:
result = digit
print(result + end = '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Each number from digits are called one by one in for loop and the last number is 9 which will be printed.